# Aplicar un estilo a el unico elemento pulsado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

tengo un problema, es que estoy utilizado jquery, y necesito que al pulsar un elemento se le aplique un estilo, el problema viene a que todos los elementos tiene la misma clase y se que se puede evaluar con el objeto evento que recibe la función, pero eso solo es cuando tienes un X numero de elemento los cuales tu conoces, pero los elementos que están vienen de una consulta de la BBDD, asi que es un problema aplicarle el estilo a ese único elemento clickado, por aqui dejo el codigo:

```
 <div class="tarjeta-imagen">
      <img src="./assets/img/perfil.jpg" alt="" class="img-card">
           <div class="tarjeta-footer">
                 Texto de prueba
            </div>
</div>
```

JQ:

```
  $(".tarjeta-imagen").click( function(e){

    var elEvento = e;

    $(".tarjeta-footer").css({

        background: '#4BD19B'

    });

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución lleva dos partes.

1. Agrega un monitor (event listener) a cada uno de los elementos. Una forma de hacerlo es usando forEach.
2. Usa la función `this` para para modificar las propiedades del elemento sobre el que se ha hecho clic.

Lo anterior se puede hacer con JavaScript puro. A continuación un ejemplo.

Se muestra una tabla de 3 x 3. Al hacer clic en un celda se agregará un texto y color de fondo a la celda cliqueada.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('td'), function(td) {
  td.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.innerHTML = '¡Clic!';
    this.style.background = '#4BD19B';
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A continuación un ejemplo usando jQuery

```js
$('td').on('click',function() {
    this.innerHTML = '¡Clic!';
    this.style.background = '#4BD19B';
  });
```

```css
td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando el operador `this`, lo he probado de la siguiente manera;

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tarjeta-imagen").click( function(){
    
          $(this).css({
              background: '#4BD19B'
          });
      })
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div class="tarjeta-imagen">
          <img src="./assets/img/perfil.jpg" alt="" class="img-card">
               <div class="tarjeta-footer">
                     Texto de prueba
                </div>
    </div>
     <div class="tarjeta-imagen">
          <img src="./assets/img/perfil.jpg" alt="" class="img-card">
               <div class="tarjeta-footer">
                     Texto de prueba
                </div>
    </div>
```

En general, el valor de this está determinado por cómo se llama a la función. No puede ser establecida por una asignación en tiempo de ejecución, y esto puede ser diferente cada vez que la función es llamada.

Documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this